# Configure file creation output directory of Batch script, when it is called by a seperate script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, directory

I currently have a Batch script that produces a file in the current working directory (a.bat), but I am unable to edit it.
I also have a second Batch script (b.bat) that calls it.

I would like to be able to change the output directory of a.bat, without directly editing it, possibly by implementing some form of configuration within b.bat.

Is this possible?

Comment: If you don't post the contents of the file, how are we supposed to work it out? Voodoo?

Comment: changing current working directory `cd ...` before calling `a.bat` if it works but depending on `a.bat` it can fail